# Single dropdown filtering for Datatable

Tags: datatables

I've been struggling for a few days now, trying to get a single dropdown to filter my table. Upon selection of the eraId, the columns should be refreshed to only  show the columns of the selected eraId.

This is how my tables looks like:

[image: table]

I've read a lot of examples on Datatables website or forums but I can't seem to find something working.

I have managed to create a dropdown menu containing the different EraIds as filter (I have simplified the example below with only 3 eraIds) but after selecting an entry in the dropdown, the table gets empty and the column list is not refreshed.

I think the problem is that I first retrieve the columns names, based on the `eraId` and then draw the table accordingly, displaying only the resources from the specific eraId. I have tried several things but did not manage.

Ideally I should callback `getPlayerResourceTable` with the selected eraId or update the column list with the resources on the selected eraId.

Javascript:

```
var columns = [];
function getPlayerResourceTable($selectedEraId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./graphs.php",
        data: { call_function : 'getResourceTableColumns', eraId: $selectedEraId},
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            columnNames = Object.keys(data.data);
            
            for (var i in data.data) {
              columns.push({data: data.data[i], 
                        title: data.data[i]});
            }
            
            $('#playerResourceTable').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                serverSide: false,
                filter: true,
                columns: columns,
                ajax: {
                    url: './graphs.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { call_function: 'playerResourceTable', column_fields : data.data, eraId: $selectedEraId}
                },
        
                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().columns( 0 ).every( function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                            .appendTo( $("#playerResourceTablesWrapper .dataTables_filter"))
                            .on( 'change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                    $(this).val()
                                );
          
                                column.search( this.value ).draw();
                            } );
          
                            select.append( '<option value="1">Era 1</option>' )
                            select.append( '<option value="2">Era 2</option>' )
                            select.append( '<option value="3">Era 3</option>' )
                    } );
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $selectedEraId = 1;
  getPlayerResourceTable($selectedEraId);

} );
```

PHP:
`getResourceTableColumns` returns the column list with query similar to `SELECT columnName FROM ages WHERE eraId = ?`

`playerResourceTable` returns the resources for each column (type of resource) with query similar to `SELECT ".$field_list." FROM user_resources`

I also thought of removing `WHERE eraId = ?` in my MySQL query and filtering the columns on the client side but no luck either.

Comment: you did not pass selected `$selectedEraId ` to PHP when you change the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up separating both functions and destroying/re-creating the table when changing Era.

```
function getColumns($selectedEraId) {
    var columns = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./graphs.php",
        data: { call_function : 'getResourceTableColumns', eraId: $selectedEraId},
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            
            for (var i in data.data) {
              columns.push({data: data.data[i], 
                        title: data.data[i]});
            }
            
            if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#playerResourceTable' ) ) {   // If the table already exists, detroy it before creating it again
                $('#playerResourceTable').DataTable().destroy();
            }
            getPlayerResourceTable($selectedEraId, columns);    // Will recreate the table with the new columns
        }
    });
}
    
    
function getPlayerResourceTable($selectedEraId, columns_to_show) {
    $city_id = 91;
    $playerResourceTable = $('#playerResourceTable').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: false,
        filter: true,
        columns: columns_to_show,
        ajax: {
            url: './graphs.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { call_function: 'playerResourceTable', column_fields : columns_to_show, city_id : parseInt($city_id)}
        },

        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns( 0 ).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                
                var select = $('<select id="selectEraId" ><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $("#playerResourceTablesWrapper .dataTables_filter"))
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );
                        column.search( this.value ).draw();
                    } );
                    
                    dropdown_string = getEraDropdown($selectedEraId);
            } );
            
            $('#selectEraId').on('change', function() {
              $selectedEraId = this.value;
              columns_to_show = getColumns($selectedEraId);
            });
        }
    });
}
```